# SQL INTERSECT from a list from subquery

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a code below:

```
SELECT p.profname
FROM professor AS p
JOIN committee c ON c.profname = p.profname
WHERE c.commname = 'EUR' AND p.profname != 'Peter'
INTERSECT
SELECT p.profname
FROM professor AS p
JOIN committee c ON c.profname = p.profname
WHERE c.commname = 'SEK'
INTERSECT
SELECT p.profname
FROM professor AS p
JOIN committee c ON c.profname = p.profname
WHERE c.commname = 'SIT'
```

The value EUR, SEK, SIT can be collected using a select statement:

```
SELECT c2.commname AS CNAME FROM committee AS c2 WHERE c2.profname = 'Peter'
```

So my question is: how to combine the select statement with my code?

UPDATE

This is my query to create table and insert values

```
create table department
(
    deptname varchar(20) primary key,
    building varchar(20) 
)
go

create table professor
(
    profname varchar(20) primary key,
    deptname varchar(20) foreign key references department(deptname)
)
go

create table committee
(
    id int identity(1,1) primary key,
    commname varchar(20) not null,
    profname varchar(20) foreign key references professor(profname)
)
go

insert into department (deptname, building) values ('Chad', 'Idaho');
insert into department (deptname, building) values ('ElSalvador', 'Nebraska');
insert into department (deptname, building) values ('SaintLucia', 'Kentucky');
insert into department (deptname, building) values ('Iceland', 'Vermont');
insert into department (deptname, building) values ('Spain', 'Nevada');
insert into department (deptname, building) values ('NewCaledonia', 'Nebraska');
insert into department (deptname, building) values ('PalestinianTerritory', 'Ohio');
insert into department (deptname, building) values ('PuertoRico', 'Hawaii');
insert into department (deptname, building) values ('EquatorialGuinea', 'Delaware');
go

insert into professor (profname, deptname) values ('Mark', 'Iceland');
insert into professor (profname, deptname) values ('Jane', 'Iceland');
insert into professor (profname, deptname) values ('Amanda', 'PalestinianTerritory');
insert into professor (profname, deptname) values ('Thomas', 'Spain');
insert into professor (profname, deptname) values ('Roger', 'PuertoRico');
insert into professor (profname, deptname) values ('Tammy', 'Iceland');
insert into professor (profname, deptname) values ('Phillip', 'Iceland');
insert into professor (profname, deptname) values ('George', 'SaintLucia');
insert into professor (profname, deptname) values ('Amy', 'NewCaledonia');
insert into professor (profname, deptname) values ('Shirley', 'PalestinianTerritory');
insert into professor (profname, deptname) values ('Peter', 'Iceland');
go

insert into committee (commname, profname) values ('SEK', 'Amy');
insert into committee (commname, profname) values ('QAR', 'Tammy');
insert into committee (commname, profname) values ('XAU', 'Amanda');
insert into committee (commname, profname) values ('MTL', 'George');
insert into committee (commname, profname) values ('SIT', 'Shirley');
insert into committee (commname, profname) values ('NZD', 'Shirley');
insert into committee (commname, profname) values ('EUR', 'Jane');
insert into committee (commname, profname) values ('EUR', 'Amy');
insert into committee (commname, profname) values ('EUR', 'George');
insert into committee (commname, profname) values ('EUR', 'Peter');
insert into committee (commname, profname) values ('SIT', 'Peter');
insert into committee (commname, profname) values ('SEK', 'Peter');
insert into committee (commname, profname) values ('SEK', 'George');
insert into committee (commname, profname) values ('SIT', 'George');
go
```

I expect to find all professors who go to the same committee with Peter
It should return **George** in this case

Comment: Running this in SQL would tell that Peter has 4 professors that share a committee with them, not only George.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query. I guess you mean we need all `profnames` with the same set of `commname` with `Peter`. In this query `HAVING` is the condition that the count of `commname` for current `profname` is the same for `profname = 'Peter'`

```
SELECT p.profname
FROM professor AS p
JOIN committee c ON c.profname = p.profname
WHERE p.profname != 'Peter'
      AND 
      c.commname IN (SELECT DISTINCT c2.commname AS CNAME 
                            FROM committee AS c2 
                            WHERE c2.profname = 'Peter')
GROUP BY p.profname
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.commname) = 
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(c2.commname)) 
                  FROM committee AS c2 
                  WHERE c2.profname = 'Peter'
        )
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo with your data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c6155/1)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.profname
FROM professor AS p
JOIN committee c ON c.profname = p.profname
WHERE c.commname in (SELECT c2.commname AS CNAME FROM committee AS c2 WHERE c2.profname = 'Peter') AND p.profname != 'Peter'
INTERSECT
SELECT p.profname
FROM professor AS p
JOIN committee c ON c.profname = p.profname
WHERE c.commname = 'SEK'
INTERSECT
SELECT p.profname
FROM professor AS p
JOIN committee c ON c.profname = p.profname
WHERE c.commname = 'SIT'
```

This is how you should do it.

Comment: I mean the select statement may return many results. EUR, SEK, SIT are only 3 of them

Comment: Can you give us an example? Of the tables and what result you desire.